# How to run same function synchronously and asynchronously

Tags: rx-java2, android-room, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am using `Room` and `RxJava2` in Android application. I have a scenario inwhich I want to same function to run `synchronously` at some point and to run `asynchronously` on other place. Below is the function:

```
@Query("SELECT * from saved_survey WHERE enumeratorId = :enumeratorId and isDeleted=:isDeleted ORDER BY savedSurveyTime  DESC")
    fun getSavedSurveyList(enumeratorId: String, isDeleted: Boolean): Flowable<List<SavedSurvey>>
```

I want to run this function synchronously when called from `IntentService` and run asynchronously when called from UI thread. I am calling this function as:

```
savedSurveyViewModel.getSavedSurveyList(enumeratorId, false)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe()
```

I dont want to make multiple functions in `repository` or `viewmodel`. Any efficient approach will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Same function can be used for synchronous and asynchronous. `RxJava2` provides both of these behaviours.

**Asynchronous**

```
savedSurveyViewModel.getSavedSurveyList(enumeratorId, false)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe()
```

**Synchronous**

```
savedSurveyViewModel.getSavedSurveyList(enumeratorId, false).blockingSubscribe()
```

or

```
savedSurveyViewModel.getSavedSurveyList(enumeratorId, false).blockingSingle()
```

Thanks.